# MySQL update with conditions based on another tables value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL. I would like to set the value of the 'Total' column to be equal to the Ratio x (Table A column if the item begins with A) or Ratio x (Table B column if the item begins with B) and the Month column in both tables match.

```
create table zeus(id int primary key,
                  Month varchar(10),
                  Items varchar(20),
                  Ratio decimal(3,2),
                  Total decimal(10,2));


create table ares(id int primary key,
                  Month varchar(10),
                  `Value A` decimal(10,2),
                  `Value B` decimal(10,2));
```

| id | Month | Items | Ratio | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | May | Bag | 0.50 |  |
| 2 | May | Apple | 0.3 |  |
| 3 | May | Bottle | 0.25 |  |
| 4 | May | Acorn | 0.1 |  |
| 5 | May | Alarm Clock | 0.6 |  |
| 6 | May | Bottle | 0.25 |  |

| id | Month | Total A | Total B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | May | 600 | 800 |
| 2 | June | 780 | 400 |

I have tried this

```
update zeus
set Total = (CASE 
                      WHEN Items like ('A%') and Month = 'May'
                        THEN Ratio * (select(ares.`Value A`)
                        WHERE Month = 'May')
                      WHEN Items like ('B%') and Month = 'May'
                        THEN Ratio * (select(ares.`Value B`)
                        WHERE Month = 'May')
                        END);
```

But I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want:

```
update zeus
inner join ares using (Year,Month)
set zeus.Total = case
    when zeus.Items like 'A%' then ares.`Value A` * zeus.Ratio
    when zeus.Items like 'B%' then ares.`Value B` * zeus.Ratio
end
```

That will set the Total to null if Items starts with neither A nor B; add an else clause if you want it set to blank or left as the existing zeus.Total value.

Note that having arrays of column names for related values rather than a separate table with one value per row is usually considered bad database design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Seems I accidentally omitted something during my question. If there was a 'Year' column in both tables and you wanted to perform the same task but only where Month and Year were the same instead of only Month. How would you go about it? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Also, the value I want in my Total column is not 'Value A' but 'Value A' multiplied by the Ratio

Comment: added ratio, and changed to join using year too.  or you can be explicit, for instance if the columns have different names in different tables, like `inner join ares on ares.Year=zeus.Year and ares.Month=zeus.Month`